# XMLSerializer - Parameter less Construction

Tags: c#, constructor, xmlserializer

I have the following class:

```
    [Serializable]
public class ClassOne : ClassTwo
{
    private string _parameterOne;
    private string _parameterTwo;
    private string _parameterThree;

    public Category (string parameterOne, string parameterTwo, string parameterThree)
    {
        _parameterOne = parameterOne;
        _parameterTwo = parameterTwo;
        _parameterThree = parameterThree;
    }
}
```

I then want to make use of the XMLSerializer:

```
private void Serialize()
{
    XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new xmlSerializer(typeof(ClassOne));

    xmlSerializer.Serialize(stream, object);
}
```

However, I can't serialize that class because it does not have a parameterless construction... How can I practically resolve this situation?

Comment: Add a parameter less constructor!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add empty constructor. And you should use public properties for fields that you want to serialize

```
[Serializable]
public class ClassOne : ClassTwo
{
    private string _parameterOne;
    private string _parameterTwo;
    private string _parameterThree;

    public Category() { }
    public Category (string parameterOne, string parameterTwo, string parameterThree)
    {
        _parameterOne = parameterOne;
        _parameterTwo = parameterTwo;
        _parameterThree = parameterThree;
    }
}
```